# How to vertical align text within a list containing superscript?

Tags: html, css

I want to align text within a list of items containing *superscript* such that the main text are equally spaced vertically:

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li>Shape: Rectangle</li>
 <li>Length: 5m</li>
 <li>Breadth: 3m</li>
 <li>Area: 15m<sup>2</sup></li>
 <li>Color: Blue</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried tinkering with the `display`, `height`, `line-height` and `vertical-align` properties in CSS. But none seems to work. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that [superscripts tend to make line spacing uneven](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/linespacing.html). Setting `line-height` to a sufficiently large value like 1.3 may help. But in general, it is best to avoid using the `sup` element and construct your own superscript element, using `span` and style that creates a superscript using relative positioning (which does not affect line spacing, unlike the vertical alignment caused by `sup`).

In this specific case, there is a much simpler and better approach: instead of `<sup>2</sup>`, use `&sup2;`, or enter directly the superscript two character “²” (on Windows, you can do that using Alt 0178). Being a normal character, it does not affect line spacing, and being designed by a typographer, it can be expected to look better than any superscript 2 created using HTML or CSS.

Comment: This is certainly very very helpful, you deserve more votes than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/TgqQY/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span></span><span>Shape: Rectangle<span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Length: 5m</span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Breadth: 3m</span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Area: 15m<sup>2</sup></span></li>
    <li><span></span><span>Color:</span> <span>Blue</span></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
li { background: red; height: 50px; margin: 3px 0; padding: 5px 0; }
li span:first-child { height: 100%; }
li span { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on format, you can try lowering the font size just before calling the `<sup>` tag:

> ...`<br/>` <li>Area: 15m<font
>
> size=-1><sup>2</sup></font></li>
>
> ...`<p/>`

There is still a slight spacing gap, but it is not really noticeable.